# Why is this Google Maps polyline not removing?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I've fixed my issue, my question is why this code leaves segments of old polyline.

Note: polyline is a List of type LatLng

```
for (int i = 0; i < polyline.size(); ++i)
    {
        polyline.get(i).remove();
        polyline.remove(i);
    }
```

but if I remove the polyline.remove(i) (removing list elements) it works just as expected. What is going on here? It doesn't make sense to me because the polyline.remove(i); is happening after the actual polyline removal, so I'd expect it not to affect it in any way.

```
for (int i = 0; i < polyline.size(); ++i)
    {
        polyline.get(i).remove();
    }
    polyline.clear()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're currently removing *every other element*.

When you remove element 0, everything else "shifts along" so that there's a new element 0... but you're leaving that alone, and moving on to element 1 (which has the value that element 2 used to have).

Options:

- Always remove from start, just with a while loop:

  ```
  while (polyline.size() > 0)
  {
      polyline.get(0).remove();
      polyline.remove(0);
  }
  ```
- Remove from the end

  ```
  for (int i = polyline.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
  {
      polyline.get(i).remove();
      polyline.remove(i);
  }
  ```
- Call remove on each line and then clear the collection as you're doing in your second snippet
- The same, but with an enhanced for loop:

  ```
  for (LatLng point : polyline)
  {
      point.remove();
  }
  polyline.clear();
  ```

Comment: @MaciejGórski: It's possible that the question is wrong, but it does explicitly say: "polyline is a List of type LatLng"

Comment: Yes, sorry. I noticed that statement after the edit. And yes, it is incorrect. Should I edit it back?

Comment: @MaciejGórski: Will roll it back myself.

Comment: also need map.clear();. but should be careful about other things on map! :)